# Running the app created in c# by double clicking on mp3 file but getting an error

Tags: c#, wpf, mp3, exe

I want to run an mp3 file in myplayer.exe (I have coded and developed in c#) .
But I am getting this error - abc.mp3 is not a valid Win32 application.

I used this code to get the filepath - 
...

```
    if
    ((AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData != null)     
      &&     
    (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ActivationArguments.ActivationData.Length>0))
       {
            string fname = "No filename given";
            try
                 {
                 fname = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.
                         ActivationArguments.ActivationData[0];

                Uri uri = new Uri(fname);

               fname = uri.LocalPath;

                this.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] = fname;
      }

         catch (Exception ex)
                 { }

        base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

The above code in the app.xaml.cs

and In the mainWindow.xaml.cs , this is the code I have used!

```
  public CubeWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainContainer_Loaded);
         }

 void MainContainer_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
  if(System.Windows.Application.Current.Properties["ArbitraryArgName"] != null)
    {
      string fname=System.Windows.Application.Current.
                    Properties["ArbitraryArgName"].ToString();
       me.Source = new Uri(fname, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
       me.Play(); //me is the mediaelement
     }
    }
```

Please let me know to correct this.. and the cause of this error! 
Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: Where do you get the error? How did you associate MP3s?

Comment: Why don't you use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()`?

Comment: @SLaks , In my folders in the system... I have mp3 files. I doble clicked onto them.. 
P.S- I ahve already changed the file type open with property and set my exe as the default player.

Comment: But I still don't know where I went wrong! If I browse through the media files by opening them through the player.. they're wrking well.. But when in a normal folder i double clik them I get this error!

Comment: Where do you get the error? What is in `HKCU\.mp3`?

Comment: Does your app fire?  You have been asked three times now where do you get that error?

Comment: I didnt get when you ask where do you get the error.!!

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error you're getting, it seems as though you're trying to execute an MP3. That won't work.

When you try to open a file - say, a txt file - by double clicking, Windows checks the registry for the default application for that file - which in most setups, would be Notepad. It then sends this command:

```
"<System32 Directory>\Notepad.exe" <filename>
```

or

```
"C:\Windows\System32\Notepad.exe" "C:\Users\user\Desktop\test1.txt"
```

So the first command line argument is the filename.

Long story short: If your program is started through trying to open an MP3 in Windows Explorer, you need to get and save the command line arguments for reference somewhere in your project.

To do this, you can use `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` or pass them from `static void main` in `Program.cs` to your first form's constructor.

Comment: I am sorry but can you please elaborate how Environment.GetcommandArgs is different from ActivationArgs I have used?? As far as I know.. THey are used to obtain the file that was double clicked!

Answer (score 0):

From the error description you had given it looks like a problem related to command line parameters.
You have to read the command line parameters for your application.
In WPF you can process your Application_Startup event to read the command line arguments.
You can follow [this](http://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/19/how-to-process-command-line-parameters-or-arguments-in-a-wpf-application/) to understand use of command line arguments in wpf.
[This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/3dbfb9a3-4e14-41d1-afbb-1790420706fe) will help you get into the details of playing MP3 files in C#..

Hope this will help.